# If $\frac{a+b}2$ is rational, can we say that $a,b$ are rational?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, rationality-testing

The question is if it's given that 
$$ {a+b\over 2} \in \Bbb Q $$
prove or disprove $a,b \in \Bbb Q$.

Since it is to disprove, I tried the following method by using examples.

Take $$a = 1 + \sqrt{2} \in I \,(
\text{Irrational}Numbers) $$
 Take $$b = 1 - \sqrt{2} \in I \,(\text{Irrational Numbers}) $$
$$ {a+b\over 2} = {1 + \sqrt{2} + 1 - \sqrt{2}\over 2} = 1 \in \Bbb Q $$

Is this sufficient to disprove the above statement? Or is there any better way?

Comment: That works, although you could leave out the ones for an even simpler example.

Comment: @AMPerrine you mean $ \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2} = 0 $ ? thought that would seem like a special case

Comment: Seems perfectly correct. There's no "better way" I guess! Well you could also have taken $a=2i$ and $b=0$ , it's maybe quicker

Comment: @krirkrirk i means iota? but that would make $ {a+b\over 2} $ irrational isnt it?

Comment: @ManZzup $0$ is still a rational number, so it works fine as well.  If you were to remove the division by 2 in the proof title, this shows an interesting fact.  You should know that if you add two whole numbers you get back another whole number.  If you add two integers you get back an integer.  If you add two rationals you get back a rational.  This example shows however that if you add two irrationals you don't always get back an irrational.  We say *"Irrational numbers are not closed under addition"*

Comment: whooops I meant $a = i$ and $b=-i$ :)

Comment: @JMoravitz awweesome =)

Comment: @krirkrirk ahh yeaah then it's a better example i guess :)

Comment: That's sufficient. To disprove something, you just need one counterexample.

Comment: "thought that would seem like a special case" — every counterexample is a special case.

Comment: We have an infinite family of counterexamples: $\rho+\acute\alpha$ and $\rho-\acute\alpha$ for any rational $\rho$ and irrational $\acute\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any better way?

Since all you have to do is give a counterexample, there is not much need to try to *improve* your "disproof"; however, a simpler and more all-encompassing consideration would lend itself to multiple counterexamples.

Let $\mathbb{I}$ denote the set of irrational numbers. Suppose that $a,b\in\mathbb{I}$, where $b=-a$. Then
$$
\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{a+(-a)}{2}=\frac{0}{2}\in\mathbb{Q},\;a,b\not\in\mathbb{Q}.\tag{1}
$$
How is this an improvement? Well, you don't have to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. You also don't have to prove that the sum of a rational number and an irrational number is irrational (i.e., $1+\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, which you seem to take for granted).

Basically, in $(1)$, there is minimal legwork done for a consideration that provides groundwork for countless counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of counter examples.
(a+b)/2=x
a+b=2x
As long a and b add up to a even number, its possible.
Assume 0 < a < 1
(odd number+a)+(even number+[1-a])=odd number+1=even number
You also can change this a little bit and you can get way more equations for counter examples.

Comment: For some basic information about writing maths on this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).